# bash command to wait until TCP port is opened

Tags: java, linux, bash, microservices

I want my micro services to open in a new command line and run it from there one after the other. below is my bash script

```bash
################ first SERVER #####################
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'java -jar server/target/first-server.jar; exec bash'

################ second SERVER #####################
export service_port=8771
export host_name=firstdomain
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'java -Dservice.port="${service_port}" -Dhost.name="${host_name}" -jar eureka/target/second-server.jar; exec bash'
```

The problem is it that i want to start my **"second-server.jar"** after successfully started the **"first-server.jar"**. I can detect that by checking if the service is listening to network port. Is there any way to archive this? **sleep** bash command is not a option for me.

Comment: The question is, how will you know that first-server.jar successfully started?  (Will a port be open?  Will a file be created?)  The answer to THAT question is what will solve your problem.

Comment: say that the port is going to be open if the microservice is started.  then what will be the bash command

Comment: `netstat -na | grep LISTENING | grep :<port_number>`

Comment: checked, but it doesn't show anything on that port. so is there any other thing? that i can do

Comment: Make sure you have the `-a` option.  I accidentally left it out.  If that does not return anything, the port is not open and first-server.jar did not start successfully.  If first-server.jar creates log files, you can parse the log files.

Comment: You're not actually typing in the `<` and `>`, are you?

Comment: Have you tried to chain those two commands using `&&` ? For example `ls file && echo "hello"`. The last command `echo "hello"` will not be executed if the first command was not successful. Try it with a non valid file to see how it behaves

Answer (score 7):

Basically, you need to use `sleep` command. But you can use it in a loop checking continuously if the port became available. But how to check availability of the port?

One option is to use `netstat` command as suggested by Jack. The proper usage is:

```
netstat -tna | grep 'LISTEN\>' | grep ':NNNN\>'
```

where `NNNN` is the port. To make that a condition to wait on, you can write following loop:

```
while ! netstat -tna | grep 'LISTEN\>' | grep -q ':NNNN\>'; do
  sleep 10 # time in seconds, tune it as needed
done
```

Please mind the `-q` option in the last instance of `grep`.

The other option is to check, if you can connect to port:

```
{
  while ! echo -n > /dev/tcp/localhost/NNNN; do
    sleep 10
  done
} 2>/dev/null
```

Depending on the distribution you are using and the options bash has been compiled with, this method may or may not working.

Another option to check if port is accessible is to use nc:

```
while ! nc -q0 localhost 2222 < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; do
  sleep 10
done
```

You can replace localhost with your hostname or ip address.

Comment: My `netstat` does not put those extra characters after "LISTENING" and "NNNN".

Comment: @Jack Those extra characters are for `grep` pattern. Consider following command: `echo -e '80\n8080' | grep ^80` and `echo -e '80\n8080' | grep '^80\>'`. And `LISTENING` is for Unix based socket. Network sockets in listen state are shown as `LISTEN`.

Comment: If I put `\>` as part of the `grep` string, it fails.